# How to call functions in MinGW gdb?

Tags: c++, windows, gdb, mingw-w64

I am trying to display the output of function calls in **MinGW gdb** on Windows 10.

I defined the following function `foo()` in my `.cpp` file.

```
void foo()
{
  cout<<"Hi foo!"<<"\n";
}
```

**When I try `(gdb) call foo()` or `(gdb) p foo()`, `gdb` crashes and returns back to command prompt.**

So I tried displaying the list of callable functions, by typing `(gdb) call` and hitting `<tab>`. The list does contain the function `foo()`.

Moreover, `(gdb) ptype foo` outputs `void (void)`.
These suggest the function `foo()` exists.

The `gdb` version is `GNU gdb (GDB) 8.1` from `MinGW x86_64-posix-seh`, downloaded from this [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/).

**Please help me display the output of function calls in **MinGW gdb**.**

Comment: The 64bit gdb-8.1 had this bug: win64: [crash inside call_function_by_hand()](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22854). This is very likely the issue you are facing. It was fixed in 8.2

Comment: @ssbssa Thanks for pointing it out.